# What is the best way to compare values in two Properties objects?

Tags: java

I have two Properties instances which contain same keys but may contain different values(strings). What is the best way to check if the values are identical in both the instances.

Right now I am using if conditions to check like below

```
if(!p1.getProperty("x").equals(p2.getProperty("x")) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is the nature of the property,if the property is an object you better compare the hashcode also,but if they are primitive,you can use ==

Comment: as far as I am concerned the example you posted is comparing 2 strings.

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan by definition, in Java properties are strings. The `Properties` class documentation says so. And you should *never* compare hashcodes as many strings can have the same hashcode.

Comment: Clarify. If you want to compare the `Properties` objects themselves, just use `equals()`. If you want to compare the values for equal keys, ditto.

Comment: @RealSkeptic,you use both equals and hashcode,there are slim chances that collusion can happen at the same time on both values and hashcode,beside still you can override equals and hashcode inside your object too

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan If you want to find a bucket in a hash table, use `hashCode()`. That's all it's for. If you want to test equality, use `equals()`.

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan there is no need to use the hash code at all if you use `equals`. The hash codes are *always* equal if the `equals` returns true.

Comment: @RealSkeptic,true

Comment: Updated but not clarified. Do you want to compare the `Properties` objects themselves, or only the values for the keys which both `Properties` share?

Comment: Values for the keys. Not the properties instances. Also it is guaranteed that both the properties instances will contain the same keys always

Comment: So to be clear, you only want to compare the values for the intersection of the key sets? You can see that once you define the problem properly, the question practically answers itself.

Comment: If it is guaranteed that the keys are exactly the same, then you **should** compare the properties objects themselves. That gives `true` if the values are the same, and `false` if there is at least one value that is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Properties` is a subclass of `HashTable`, which overrides `equals`. You can simply compare the instances using `equals`:

```
properties1.equals(properties2)
```

But this won't tell you *what* is different.

To do that, you can get the keys using `properties.keySet()`, and then compare the values between the two instances:

```
for (String key : properties1.keySet()) {
  String value1 = properties1.get(key);
  String value2 = properties2.get(key);

  // Compare, e.g. value1.equals(value2).
  // But may need to take into account missing values.
}
```

Note that this is asymmetrical, in the sense that it looks for the values for which values exist in `properties1`. If you want to search for the intersection (or union) of the keys, just build that set first:

```
Set<String> keys = new HashSet<>(properties1.keySet());
// For intersection:
keys.retainAll(properties2.keySet());
// For union:
// keys.addAll(properties2.keySet());

for (String key : keys) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value=p1.getProperty("x");
if (value == null) {
                    if (!(p2.getProperty("x")==null && p2.containsKey("x")))
                        return true;
} else {
                    if (!value.equals(p2.getProperty("x")))
                        return true;
}
```